# MacBook Core 2 Duo: "Require password to wake this computer from sleep" No longer works

Tags: sleep, osx-leopard, screensaver, system-preferences

After recently updating my MacBook to 10.5.8, I've noticed that the option to require a password to wake the computer from sleep/screensaver no longer works.  I put the thing to sleep, and it comes right back to whatever I was doing; no password.

I'm able to toggle the option on or off, but no amount of setting or resetting seems to change it.  It definitely worked before the update.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post a picture showing your Security preferences pane, so we can see the complete set of options you have selected. I believe this might be an OS 10.5 bug, that is not present in 10.6.8 nor in 10.7.   Did you really mean "10.5.8", or did you type that wrong?

Comment: Posted!  And I did mean 10.5.8; I'd not done system updates in a very long time, and after performing all of them, 10.5.8 is where I wound up.

Answer (score 0):

I dragged this file to the desktop, then rebooted:
`/Users/<my username>/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist`
This caused the OS to generate a new file, and my Laptop is now locking like a champ.